# How to get the list of gcp compute instances IP address through API externally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

what is the procedure for getting the list of all the IP address of google compute instances through its API's and how to provide OAuth 2 access token externally

When I am trying to access via the API given by GCP

https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances

I am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

How do i authenticate ?

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: There are some resources such as https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin which mention how to achieve this. How are you consuming the API? Are you simply doing a call through cURL or are you using a client library?

Comment: I am just doing a curl operation, is it necessary to a use a client library to achieve this? If so can you please share any template

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get an access token for a curl call to a Google Cloud API is to use the Cloud SDK (provided you have it [installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) and configured).

Once you've confirmed you're logged in with the correct user or service account (`gcloud auth list`) you can get an access token for a user account by running:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

or for a service account you've configured as default:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

You'll need to pass that token as Authorization header to authenticate your call. You can integrate the gcloud command in your curl call like this:

```
curl https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT/zones/ZONE/instances -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
```

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the response and print only an array of IP objects, for example:

```
curl https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT/zones/ZONE/instances -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" | jq '[.items | .[] | {ip: .networkInterfaces[].accessConfi
gs[].natIP}]'
```

It'll print a response of the form:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "XX.XXX.XX.XXX"
  },
  {
    "ip": "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX"
  }
]
```